# What is the expectation of $X$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

Let the random variable $X$ represent the number of times a fair coin needs to be tossed till two consecutive heads appear for the first time. The expectation of $X$ is ?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: i approached this problem as :  since we need minimum 2 tosses to get two heads. starting from two tosses we get expectation as 2*(1/4) + 3*(1/8) + 4*(1/16)+ ... and so on. is this a correct way or am i doing something wrong.

Comment: @empty-soul Add your working in your original post by editing it.

Comment: @empty-soul: What tools do you have?  Do you know Markov chains?  Also, are you sure about your probability mass for the case when it takes 4 flips?

Comment: anyone please post an answer.